# Why do the icons in my footer move when I hover over the third image on my homepage?

Tags: html, css

http://jonathan-james.github.io/

Above is a link to my github/pages site I recently launched. Super excited because it's a big jump in the right direction towards becoming a professional developer. I have a bug on my home page I need help resolving.

If you go to the link, you'll see that when you hover over the main content items on the home page, they "jump". That is because on hover their margin is set to 0 which makes this cool effect happen.

For some reason when a user hovers over the third item on the page (Technical support) the icons in the footer become right aligned! I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours and frankly I'm not quite sure what's going on. I could really use another set of eyes to help me figure out what is going on here.

I'd be happy to link the page code, but its pretty lengthy so I'll only do this if requested as I assume most developers would rather inspect elements anyway.

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so I appreciate the help and hope to hear back soon! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to your footer element.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, this worked! Would you mind explaining why you went with this option rather than adding overflow:auto; to .wrap as mentioned above?

Comment: Yeah, the overflow worked, I also tried it. I went for this option because you have floating elements inside `.wrap`, particularly the boxes (inside the `a` element).

Comment: `clear:both;` is actually the old solution, and the `overflow: auto` is the new one. Refer to this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: Actually there's also another way, but those two have less coding.

Comment: Thanks again my friend, I appreciate the feedback greatly.

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow: auto;` to `.wrap` 
Good luck in front-end development!

Answer (score 0):

While other answers is right. You can also add

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

on `footer`.